# RSelenium: clear input field

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I am automating chrome with RSelenium and need to clear an input field before filling it. I have tried this:

```
e <- rd$findElement("name", "keyword")$clear()
```

and this:

```
e <- rd$findElement("name", "keyword") %>% clear()
```

and this:

```
e6 <- rd$findElement("name", "sc.keyword").clear()
```

and this:

```
e$clear()
```

and this:

```
e %>% clear()
```

But all I get is an error message:

```
Error in clear(.) : could not find function "clear"
```

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
e$clearElement()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Andrei